# Search for previous versions of a Nuget from Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, nuget, version, xamarin-studio

Using Xamarin Studio on Mac, how can you list all the versions of a NuGet Package (current version, old versions).

What is the syntax for `version` when using the **Package Manager** GUI?

As an example, how can I list all and only the versions for **MvvmCross - StarterPack** (not just **MvvmCross**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mac Xamarin Studio 6.1 and later

Readily available in a popup menu.

[image: Popup]

---

#### Mac Xamarin Studio (prior 6.1)

Solution > Packages > Add Packages...

```
nuggetIdentifier version:
```

[image: Search bar in Xamarin Studio]

**Explanation**

- Use the NuGet **id** instead of the NuGet name
- Use *unspecified version* to list all the available versions. Leading   and trailing `:` required
- Use specific version (`version:4.1.6`) for just *that* one

**Note**

The `version:` syntax is compatible with **Show pre-release packages**, but not with the quoted string search, such as `"MvvmCross StarterPack"`.

Comment: In Xamarin Studio 6.1 there is a version drop down where you can select the version instead of having to remember the version search syntax.